# Disable checkbox in django admin if already checked

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a simple but problematic question for me. How can I disable checkbox,  if input is already filled/checked? I must disable some fields after first filling them. Thank you for all your ideas.

Sierran

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in solution to this problem, if you want the fields to display dynamically you will always need a custom javascript/ajax solution! You might be able to hack the admin view and template to conditionally show/not show widgets for a field, but if you want to do it dynamically based on user behaviors in the admin, you'll be using javascript.

It's not so terrible, though. At least the Django admin templates have model- and instance-specific ids to give you granular control over your show/hide behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "has_delete_permissions" on the admin form definition

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
   return False
```